# C++ Recursive Sorting by Divide and Conquer & Iterative sorting

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, recursion, iteration

Could you guys please explain to me, in layman's terms, with or without code examples, how divide and conquer array sorting using recursion works, and how it's different than iterative array sorting? I am completely lost here.

Comment: What do you mean? Divide and Conquer works always the same: split in two (or more) subproblems, solve the subproblems recursively and finally join the solutions. You can do this in many ways: Sort the first half array, then the second half then merge the two sorted arrays (merge-sort approach). Or take a number in the array, put all the elements less than the number in a subarray, the bigger elements in another. Sort these two subarrays and concatenate them. (quick-sort approach). No idea what do you want about iterative sortig. What's the meaning of "iterative" in that case?

Comment: This is the prompt I'm given. I'm not given much of a background on how to get it done, though. I'm sort of at a loss...

You are to design and implement three functions, two of which will use recursion.
The first is a sorting function that will sort an array when given the array and the size. The function will use recursion to sort the array using the divide and conquer method.
The second is a searching function that also uses recursion and implements binary search on the array.
The last function will sort the array iteratively (not using recursion).

Answer (score 1):

There are several algorithms for iterative array sorting, all of them involve comparing elements and moving them as necessary to get the array sorted.

One way to do a recursive solution is to have a base case where an iterative sort is used if the array is very small, for a larger array it will split the array into smaller chunks and recurse.  Each of these chunks will be returned sorted and then they are merged (merging sorted arrays is fast).

So in pseudo code:

```
function recursive_sort(array) {
    if (array is small)
        sort array iteratively and return
    else
        // split the array
        let array1 be the first half of array
        let array2 be the second half of array
        // sort the chunks
        recursive_sort(array1)
        recursive_sort(array2)
        // merge() describes the operation of merging two sorted arrays (fast!)
        array = merge(array1, array2)
}
```

Note that the base case for the recursive sort may just be that `array` is empty or has only 1 element.  In this case nothing needs to be done in the base case so there is no dependency on an iterative sorting method.

There are of course other recursive algorithms that can be used, but the basic idea is the same: each recursive call will use some smaller chunk of the original array and those chunks are combined at the end to give a sorted result.